# How to query LDAP group membership with curl?

Tags: curl, ldap, ldap-query

I would like to use `curl` on the command line to check if a `$USER` is a member of the LDAP group `$GROUP`.

This works:

```
curl --user $CREDS \
     "ldaps://ldap.foo.com/DC=ads,DC=foo,DC=com??sub?(sAMAccountName=$USER)" \ 
   | grep -a "memberOf: CN=$GROUP,OU=Distribution,OU=Groups,DC=ads,DC=foo,DC=com"
```

Unfortunately, that call takes quite some time and it returns a lot of info that I am not interested in. Do you know if a more efficient way exists?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You could try :

```
curl --user $CREDS \
     "ldaps://ldap.foo.com/DC=ads,DC=foo,DC=com?memberOf?sub?(&(sAMAccountName=$USER)(memberOf=CN=$GROUP,OU=Distribution,OU=Groups,DC=ads,DC=foo,DC=com))"
```

Which will

- For the filter : retrieve only users who have `sAMAccountName=$USER` AND `memberOf=CN=$GROUP,OU=Distribution,OU=Groups,DC=ads,DC=foo,DC=com` (it will make the filtering server side than with your `grep` command on all the users attributes)
- For the `memberOf` addition (before the `?sub`) specify that you want only the memberOf attribute to be retrieved.

  If the filter change did the trick, try to just retrieve the `dn` for example to limit the ouput, because if no attribute is specified, every attributes are returned

For more information : https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19396-01/817-7616/ldurl.html

Comment: That works very well! Thank you very much! I wonder about one thing, though: the query above returns many groups that $USER is a member of?

Comment: If you let the `...?memberOf?sub?...` it will retrieve every groups the user is a member of. If you do not need this information, that's why I said on the second point :  If the filter change did the trick, try to just retrieve the dn for example to limit the ouput. The request would be something like : `ldaps://ldap.foo.com/DC=ads,DC=foo,DC=com?dn?sub?...`. As the DN should always be returned, it will not add any other information

Comment: Perfect! Now I understand it :)